# Visual Studio 2010 not showing Crystal Report Viewer of Printing Tab in Toolbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports, toolbox

Scenario :

I have **windows form Application** and want to generate Crystal reports. I have downloaded Crystal report of SAP and Installed, designed all crystal reports (made data set,table adapter etc )but I can't add crystal report viewer because I can't see **"Crystal report viewer and crystal report Document"** that in Reporting Tab but i downloaded one sample project from internet regarding crystal report i find there **"Crystal report viewer "**, so I match all references of that project and libraries used in that class but didn't find any crystal report viewer in reporting section of Toolbox.

Problem :

I can't view **"Crystal report viewer and Crystal Report Document"** in Toolbox.

Please help me or suggest me some suggestion to overcome on this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) In project Properties window in the Application tab change the Target Framework from "`.Net Framework 4.0 client profile`" to ".`Net Framework 4.0`"

2) Added the `CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms` reference to project
(in solution explorer right click in Reference folder and choose "`Add Reference`" --> for newbies such me)

Now you can able to see `CrystalReportViewer`.

Please mark as accepted answer if it works for you.

Comment: thanks, but could you please tell me that whay it was not showing in target frame work ".Net Framework 4.0 client profile" but showing in ".Net Framework 4.0" ?

Comment: Because CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms is a part of ".Net Framework 4.0" not ".Net Framework 4.0 client profile"

Comment: thanks, but is that will make any problem while deploying this application on my client machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Toolbox to Choose Toolbox items and select Crystal Report Viewer from the list of available component.Now it should appear in the toolbox.

Comment: thanks for reply, i add that but still not showing in my project.

Comment: No! how can i verify ?

Comment: In project Properties window in the Application tab change the Target Framework from ".Net Framework 4.0 client profile" to ".Net Framework 4.0"